# Retrieve python traceback format from string

Tags: python, traceback

I have a string that is a python traceback collapsed into a single line. I want to retrieve the multiline format of the traceback for the sake of readability. What is the best way to achieve it?

I see that traceback module has similar functionality, but I don't see how to pass a string as an argument there:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html

Example input:

```
'Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> Exception'
```

Example output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Exception
```

Comment: Does the string still contain line breaks? Can you give an example?

Comment: It does not contain brakes

Comment: you should at least give us an example of what your string looks like and what you want it to look like

Comment: updated with example input and output